# why throw should be always between curly brace?

Tags: javascript, throw

I had a situation like code below and since it's an arrow function and for a single line of code in arrow functions , no curly braces are required, I didn't use that and It works just fine.

```
const test = new Promise((resolve, failure) => {
failure("mistake");
});
const handler = test.catch(() => console.log("it's ok"));
```

but in code below when I typed `throw` without any curly braces, it just threw an exception:

```
const test = new Promise((resolve, failure) => {
failure("mistake");
});
const handler = test.catch(() => throw new Error("it's not ok"));
```

but just after adding curly braces to `throw`, it started to function correctly again:

```
const test = new Promise((resolve, failure) => {
failure("mistake");
});
const handler = test.catch(() => {throw new Error("it's not ok")});
```

so I wonder why throw needs curly braces under any circumstances?

Comment: a braceless arrow function accepts an expression as its body. `throw` is not an expression, it's a statement, so a {} block is needed

Comment: there's no `throw` in your first example

Comment: my bad, I modified my comment...@AlexanderNenashev

Comment: so why for `console.log()`, code still works fine without curly braces?@AlexanderNenashev

Comment: Because `console.log()` is an expression, not a statement.

Comment: "*for a single line of code in arrow functions , no curly braces are required*" - no, not "a single line of code", but for a single **expression**. `throw` is a statement.

Answer (score 0):

> since it's an arrow function and for a single line of code in arrow functions , no curly braces are required

More accurately, for a *single expression*, no curly braces are required. The critical question is: what is an "expression"?

An expression is a piece of code that resolves to some value. So for example, `2 + 3` is an expression; it calculates and then resolves to 5. `console.log("it's ok")` is an expression; it calls a function then resolves to the function's return value (in this case, `undefined`).

But something like `let x = 2 + 3` is not an expression. It does *contain* an expression (the `2 + 3` part), but the full thing is a "statement". Statements do not resolve to a value, and so they can't really be combined with other things For example, `console.log(let x = 2 + 3)` or `let y = (let x = 2 + 3)` are not legal.

The code `throw new Error("it's not ok")` is a statement; it does not resolve to a value. Thus, it cannot be used in spots that require an expression. You can't do `let x = throw new Error("it's not ok")`, and you can't omit the curly braces of your arrow function.

Comment: so why for `console.log()`, code still works fine without curly braces? @NicholasTower

Comment: @lome1446 - Because `console.log()` returns a value, even if that value is just `undefined`. All functions return a value in javascript and `console.log()` is just a function.